# Session not replicated on session creation with Spring Boot, Session, and Redis

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-session

I'm attempting to implement a microservices architecture using Spring Cloud's Zuul, Eureka, and my own services. I have multiple services that have UIs and services and each can authenticate users using x509 security.  Now I'm trying to place Zuul in front of those services.  Since Zuul can't forward client certs to the backend, I thought the next best thing would be to authenticate the user at the front door in Zuul, then use Spring Session to replicate their authenticated state across the backend services.  I have followed the tutorial [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/28/the-api-gateway-pattern-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iv) from Dave Syer and it almost works, but not on the first request. Here is my basic setup:

- Zuul Proxy in it's own application set to route to the backend services. Has Spring security enabled to do x509 auth. Successfully auths users.  Also has Spring Session with @EnableRedisHttpSession
- Backend service also has spring security enabled. I have tried both enabling/disabling x509 here but always requiring the user to be authenticated for specific endpoints.  Also uses Spring Session and @EnableRedisHttpSession.

If you clear all the sessions and start fresh and try to hit the proxy, then it sends the request to the backend using the zuul server's certificate.  The backend service then looks up the user based on that user cert and thinks the user is the server, not the user that was authenticated in the Zuul proxy.  If you just refresh the page, then you suddenly become the correct user on the back end (the user authenticated in the Zuul proxy). The way I'm checking is to print out the Principal user in the backend controller. So on first request, I see the server user, and on second request, I see the real user. If I disable x509 on the back end, on the first request, I get a 403, then on refresh, it lets me in.

It seems like the session isn't replicated to the backend fast enough so when the user is authenticated in the frontend, it hasn't made it to the backend by the time Zuul forwards the request.

Is there a way to guarantee the session is replicated on the first request (i.e. session creation)?  Or am I missing a step to ensure this works correctly?

Here are some of the important code snippets:

Zuul Proxy:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class ZuulEdgeServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulEdgeServer.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
}
```

Zuul Config:

```
info:
  component: Zuul Server

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

zuul:
  routes:
    service1: /**

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
#    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    net.acesinc: DEBUG

security.sessions: ALWAYS
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
      key-store: classpath:dev/localhost.jks
      key-store-password: thepassword
      keyStoreType: JKS
      keyAlias: localhost
      clientAuth: want
      trust-store: classpath:dev/localhost.jks

ribbon:
    IsSecure: true
```

Backend Service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Backend Service Config:

```
spring.jmx.default-domain: ${spring.application.name}

server:
  port: 8444
  ssl:
      key-store: classpath:dev/localhost.jks
      key-store-password: thepassword
      keyStoreType: JKS
      keyAlias: localhost
      clientAuth: want
      trust-store: classpath:dev/localhost.jks

#Change the base url of all REST endpoints to be under /rest
spring.data.rest.base-uri: /rest

security.sessions: NEVER

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
#    org.springframework.web: INFO
#    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    net.acesinc: DEBUG

eureka:
  instance: 
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/
    secureVirtualHostName: ${spring.application.name}
```

One of the Backend Controllers:

```
@Controller
public class SecureContent1Controller {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecureContent1Controller.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/secure1"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public @ResponseBody String getHomepage(ModelMap model, Principal p) {
        log.debug("Secure Content for user [ " + p.getName() + " ]");
        model.addAttribute("pageName", "secure1");
        return "You are: [ " + p.getName() + " ] and here is your secure content: secure1";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, solution for your problem is described in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751700/spring-zuul-api-gateway-with-spring-session-redis-authenticate-and-route-in-sa?rq=1#answer-38867506

Comment: Awesome! It seems to be working! I already had half of that solution, and thought I had tried the second part, but I guess not cause it's working now! Thanks again for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to shobull for pointing me to [Justin Taylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751700/spring-zuul-api-gateway-with-spring-session-redis-authenticate-and-route-in-sa?rq=1#answer-38867506) to this problem. For completeness, I wanted to put the full answer here too.  It's a two part solution:

1. Make Spring Session commit eagerly - since spring-session v1.0 there is annotation property `@EnableRedisHttpSession(redisFlushMode = RedisFlushMode.IMMEDIATE)` which saves session data into Redis immediately. Documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisFlushMode.html).
2. Simple Zuul filter for adding session into current request's header:

   ```
   import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
   import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.session.Session;
   import org.springframework.session.SessionRepository;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @Component
   public class SessionSavingZuulPreFilter extends ZuulFilter {
       @Autowired
       private SessionRepository repository;

       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionSavingZuulPreFilter.class);

       @Override
       public String filterType() {
           return "pre";
       }

       @Override
       public int filterOrder() {
           return 1;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean shouldFilter() {
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public Object run() {
           RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

           HttpSession httpSession = context.getRequest().getSession();
           Session session = repository.getSession(httpSession.getId());

           context.addZuulRequestHeader("Cookie", "SESSION=" + httpSession.getId());

           log.trace("ZuulPreFilter session proxy: {}", session.getId());

           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

Both of these should be within your Zuul Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Session support currently writes to the data store when the request is committed. This is to try to reduce "chatty traffic" by writing all attributes at once.

It is recognized that this is not ideal for some scenarios (like the one you are facing). For these we have [spring-session/issues/250](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/250). The workaround is to copy [RedisOperationsSessionRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java) and invoke [saveDelta](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java#L689) anytime property is changed.

Comment: I guess you literally mean "copy" RedisOperationsSessionRepository because the RedisSession can't be overridden? Also, the line number you tried to link to saveDelta doesn't exist. I assume you mean call saveDelta at the end of the the setAttribute() method?  And then, do you just register a bean of type RedisOperationsSessionRepository to override the default?